# Find value $c$ if you have integral result

Tags: calculus, integration

Find $c$ if $$\int_1^{e^3}{\frac{16+\ln{x^c}}{x}\ln xdx}=1881$$

I am trying to do this with substitution and integration of parts but without any luck. I divided this into two integrals and I get $8\ln{x}$ for the first one but I cant seem to solve the second one. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily rewrite your integral as

$$\int_1^{e^3} \left(\dfrac{16}{x}\ln(x) + \dfrac{c\ln^2(x)}{x}\right)\ \text{d}x = 1881$$

Where I have used $\ln(x^c) = c\ln(x)$

Now, hints:

$$\int \dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}\ \text{d}x = \dfrac{\ln^2(x)}{2}$$

$$\int \dfrac{\ln^2(x)}{x}\ \text{d}x = \dfrac{\ln^3(x)}{3}$$

Now you can proceed...

Comment: There is another $\ln{x}$ that is multiplying everything. I think you didn't see it.

Comment: @user737163 Right! My bad. Gong to edit...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\ln(x^c)=c\ln(x)$ and $\dfrac{d }{dx}(\ln^3(x))=\dfrac{3\ln^2(x)}{x}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:-$\frac{16\ln(x)}{x}dx+\frac{c(\ln(x))^2}{x}dx$ put $\ln(x)=u \implies \frac{dx}{x}=du$ so we have integral as $8\ln^2(x)+c\frac{(ln(x))^3}{3}|_1^{e^3}$ . Can you take it from here?